# Как более правильно реализовать ниже представленный actionEdit?

Tags: php, yii, mysql

У нас есть массив, приходит он к нам всегда с одинаковым количеством элементов(42). Первых два элемента всегда имеют ассоциативный ключ, остальные элементы всегда числовой. Ключи у массива никогда не меняются, но значения массива приходят разные. При этом ассоциативные(если можно так назвать) элементы всегда будут присутствовать и всегда будут заполнены, что касается же числовых: они могут быть заполнены, могут быть пустыми(хотя один всегда будет заполненным), или могут быть заполнены некоторые из них. 
Юзер может изменить значения ассоциативных элементов, но не может их удалить.
Юзер может изменить/удалить все значения **Кроме Одного** у числовых элементов.

Значения массива тянутся из базы и опять(уже с учетом того, как они поменялись) должны быть записаны в базу.

**Как я сейчас реализую это?**

Все числовые элементы ссылаются на элемент "message" в базе по внешнему ключу. Я вытягиваю id "message" и удаляю его, и каскадно удаляются переводы(в нашем случаем числовые элементы). Дальше опять записываю месседж, беру его id, удаляю пустые числовые элементы макссива и записываю остающееся в базу.
Это до невозможности глупо, и я это понимаю.
Понятно, что месседж и категорию нужно апдейтить. Больше всего меня интересует решение ситуации с числовыми элементами.
Подскажите решение за которое не стыдно;)

Вот массив для наглядности:

```
array
(  
'message'  => 'Logout'  
'category' => 'layoutsMaster'  
2 => ''  
3 => ''  
4 => ''  
5 => ''  
6 => ''  
7 => ''  
8 => 'Выйти'  
9 => ''  
10 => ''  
11 => ''  
12 => ''  
13 => ''  
14 => ''  
15 => ''  
16 => ''  
17 => ''  
18 => ''  
19 => ''  
20 => ''  
21 => ''  
22 => ''  
23 => ''  
24 => ''  
25 => ''  
26 => ''  
27 => ''  
28 => ''  
29 => ''  
30 => ''  
31 => ''  
32 => ''  
33 => ''  
34 => ''  
35 => ''  
36 => ''  
37 => ''  
38 => ''  
39 => ''  
40 => ''  
41 => ''  
)
```

Comment: чето я совсем ничего не понял(( может какнить по подробнее с примером таблиц , что куда и зачем приведешь если не сложно

Comment: Давай наоборот попробую проще объяснить. 
Есть вышеуказанный массив. Что он из себя представляет? Это исходное сообщение и переводы к нему. Так вот юзер сможет изменять исходное сообщение и категорию к нему, но не сможет удалить. Переводы сможет и удалять, и изменять, и добавлять, но один перевод всё таки должен обязательно быть.

Я удаляю всё и заново записываю, но это же совсем не правильно.
Суть вопроса: как отследить внесенные изменения и сохранить? Думаю сравнивать два массива: 1 - который пришел к нам из базы и 2 - это первый, но уже изменен юзером.

Comment: если всё равно не понятно то вечером напишу развернуто(с таблицами и кодом), а то на работе сейчас;)

Comment: @Mirvelik Надеюсь, не программистом работаете? На секунду себе представил, как это, иметь такого напарника/подчинённого...

Хаотичность, даже не так, "хаос" в постановке задачи для кудесников кода не характерно.

P.S. Складывается впечатление, что вы объясняете своему коллеге за столом напротив, которому хорошо знаком проект над которым вы совместно работает.

Comment: Надейтесь, только про себя и очень тихонько, не мешайте нам(еще не постигшим дао) забавляться;)

p.s. давать оценки тааак.., с бухты барахты - вот что действительно глупо и крайне не профессионально. Давайте не переходить на личности, давайте жить дружно!
p.p.s. вопрос постараюсь раскрыть вечером.